# My CSS padding is not working on table tds

Tags: css, padding, css-tables

I have the following CSS:

```
#numpad table td
{
padding: 6px;
text-align:center;
width:80px;
height:80px;
color:#000;
font-size:larger;
background-image: url("images/button.png");
}
```

but for some reason it is not putting any padding between my button.png images. I have also tried `margin:6px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try background-position, probably in combination with background-repeat: no-repeat

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: along with making the width/height 12 pixels larger (double the padding i wanted), this worked good (and without changing my html)

Answer (score 3):

`padding` doesn't add space between background images, you'd need `margin` for that. But `margin` doesn't work on table cells. Perhaps use `img` tags for your images, then padding on the table cells will do what you want.

This will work with padding on the table cells:

```
<td>
 <img src="images/button.png" alt="nice button" />
</td>
```

Comment: thanks for the information on padding/margin for background-images/table-cells.